# SSIS package takes long time or fail eventually

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have packages deployed on a sql server 2008R2 and recently, we migrated to a new server machine, deployed with sql server 2012. I configured packages to project deployment mode and for 10 days, all packages are working smoothly, with the execution times in the same range of older server.

Since last two days, packages started to fail. I checked in detail and found that, they are taking longer time than usual, and fail due to "Protocol error in TDS stream, communication link failure and remote host forcibly closed the connection".

When I tried to run the package through ssdt, they can run successfully, but I see data transfer movement slower than I used to see, and so package execution time is much longer.

I am not sure, what has changed. I have searched the internet for the possible reason and checked the server memory and packet size, and tried match with the older server, which did not solve the problem. I suspect, SSIS logging may have causes this, but not sure how to check it?

Please help to identify the cause of this problem.

**Edit: I enabled logging in ssdt and could see that majority of time is used in rows transfer steps only. Since my package have look ups, I thought that look ups might make it slower somehow. So copied the main query to ssms and run as a normal query on this server.

About 13L rows were returned in 12 minutes. Then I run the same query on the old server, there it returned 13L rows in less than a minute. So, possibly it proves the problem somehow is related with data transfer and not specific to packages itself.
Can Someone help please.**

Comment: Your issue most likely caused by TLS and Cipher suites. Check it out here: https://community.ir.com/t5/General/How-to-use-IIS-crypto-to-disable-ciphers-and-TLS-1-0-and-1-1/td-p/11114

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You need to run IIS Crypto on both servers, and compare TLS protocols and Cipher Suites settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the solution connection, it should be ‘RetainSameConnection’ property to 'true'. This can be done both in the SSIS package under connection manager properties and in the job step properties (Configuration > Connection Managers).

Link: http://www.sqlerudition.com/what-is-the-retainsameconnection-property-of-oledb-connection-in-ssis/

Comment: Thanks. I tested the suggestion, there is no improvement in the performance, data transfer rate is very slow. As I mentioned, packages were running absolutely normal and smooth for 10 days without a single failure even with existing settings, somethings have changed or blocking.

Comment: Can you look at the control flow?

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/designing-ssis-packages-high-performance

Also, consider performance tuning.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/sql-server-2005-ssis-tuning-the-dataflow-task/

Comment: Did service account changed after migration ?